# CommandT plugin for vim will change the current working dir?

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

I just installed [CommandT](https://wincent.com/products/command-t) for Vim, and it works very well, but there's an annoying bug/problem.

It seems that CommandT would change my working dir to the file I just opened. e.g. when I reach `/foo/bar1/1.txt` , :pwd tells me the working directory is `/foo/bar1`. Then I cannot navigate to `/foo/bar2` unless manually use `:cd`.

Don't know if this is due to CommandT or some other plugin. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 3):

Include `set noautochdir` in your `~/.vimrc`, and make sure that none of your other plugins has `set autochdir` enabled.

Comment: Thank u so much. Just learned about `autochdir` in vim. :)